# How to correctly use multiple SqlSelect set/add where functions

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm piecing together an SQL query using SilverStripes SQLSelect class with some optional (frontend) filters.

When attempting to use `addWhere()` with parameters the query has no results. E.g:

```
$sql->useConjunction();
        
$sql->addWhere(['SiteTree.ClassName' => 'ResourcePage']);
        
if (self::$Filters['Tags'])
{
    $sql->addLeftJoin('ResourcePage_Tags', 'ResourcePage_Tags.ResourcePageID = SiteTree.ID');
    $sql->addWhere(['ResourcePage_Tags.ResourceTagID IN (?)' => implode(',', self::$Filters['Tags'])]);
}

if (self::$Filters['Types'])
{
    $sql->addLeftJoin('ResourcePage_Types', 'ResourcePage_Types.ResourcePageID = SiteTree.ID');
    $sql->addWhere(['ResourcePage_Types.ResourceTypeID IN (?)' => implode(',', self::$Filters['Types'])]);
}
```

If I treat it as a string, I do get the results (like I expect testing with manual SQL). E.g:

```
$sql->useConjunction();
        
$sql->addWhere("SiteTree.ClassName = 'ResourcePage'");

if (self::$Filters['Tags'])
{
   $sql->addLeftJoin('ResourcePage_Tags', 'ResourcePage_Tags.ResourcePageID = SiteTree.ID');
   $sql->addWhere('ResourcePage_Tags.ResourceTagID IN ('.implode(',', self::$Filters['Tags']).')');
}

if (self::$Filters['Types'])
{
    $sql->addLeftJoin('ResourcePage_Types', 'ResourcePage_Types.ResourcePageID = SiteTree.ID');
    $sql->addWhere('ResourcePage_Types.ResourceTypeID IN ('.implode(',', self::$Filters['Types']).')');
}
```

The generated (simplified) query found using `$sql->__toString()` is:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT SiteTree.*
FROM
    SiteTree 
LEFT JOIN 
    "ResourcePage_Tags" ON ResourcePage_Tags.ResourcePageID = SiteTree.ID 
LEFT JOIN 
    "ResourcePage_Types" ON ResourcePage_Types.ResourcePageID = SiteTree.ID
WHERE 
 (SiteTree.ClassName = ?)
 AND (ResourcePage_Tags.ResourceTagID IN (?))
 AND (ResourcePage_Types.ResourceTypeID IN (?))
```

The parameters portion of the above output is an array:

```
'ResourcePage',
1 => '38'
2 => '5,4'
```

The omitted parts of the query is some `MATCH AGAINST` and `LIMIT ORDER BY` clauses that are always there.

What have I done wrong to get two different behaviours between string and the parameterised version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example you had which was using `in (?)` and then passing an array of values will not execute correctly because the assumption is that `?` is one value when using the prepare. Which means you are now querying for one `ResourceTypeID` that is equal to `array_value1,array_value2`. You therefore need to have a placeholder (`?`) per item in the `self::$Filters['Tags']` array.

The framework does have a helper method to achieve this like so:

```php
$placeholders = DB::placeholders(self::$Filters['Tags'])
$query->addWhere([
  "ResourcePage_Types.ResourceTypeID IN ($placeholders)" => self::$Filters['Tags']
]);
```

Comment: Ah okay. I saw this example `DB::prepared_query('DELETE FROM "SiteTree" WHERE "SiteTree"."ShowInMenus" = ?', [0]);` in the docs. Cheers for that.